# Clojure with Datomic (lein-datomic) in Windows

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have set up Datomic database up and running within a Clojure project. It is working fine when running my unit tests against it BUT:

Now I want to use it for real I have:

- downloaded datomic-free-0.9.5697
- configured my clojure project with lein-datomic 0.2.0 and its instructions.
- updated profiles.clj to be:

  ```
  {:user
   {
   :java-cmd "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\bin\\java.exe"
   :plugins [[lein-datomic "0.2.0"]]
   :datomic {:install-location "C:\\Users\\myusername\\.lein\\bin\\datomic-free-0.9.5697"}}}
   }
  }
  ```

but if I now run '`lein datomic start`' I get an error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bin/transactor" (in directory "C:\Users\myusername\.lein\bin\datomic-free-0.9.5697"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
```

What is wrong with profiles.clj install-location? Is it not working, because the fact I am using **Windows**. Is there issue with path format?

"bin/transactor" is actually bin folder where transactor and transactor.cmd file exists.